# Show 40 last votes, rather than 30, on my Votes tab

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, list

On the currently-logged-in user's [Votes page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes), a list of the the last 30 votes is displayed.

I would like propose that the number of rows should be adjustable, preferably by a URL query parameter (e.g. `?page_size=40`). That way, if one were to scrape the page to get a list of votes for the day, one would only have to make one request per vote type (e.g. upvote / downvote).

If it's too much work to make it adjustable, may I please recommend changing it from 30 to 40 (or even 50)? If it were 40, one could make **one** request to the Votes page (with type = upvote or downvote) to get *all* of the upvotes/downvotes for the day. Currently one must make 2 requests for just 1 vote type. (If it were 50, it would work for close votes as well, as we have 50 of those a day).

Comment: Not sure it needs to be so focused on scraping as it makes sense to match the highest quota available regardless, but in any case it seems like a reasonable proposal.